# If Model State not valid, Partial View not being retained

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am new to MVC.  I have a parent view that enables the user to create Quotes for a customer.  An AJAX link, "Add Product" loads a partial view "EditQuoteDetail", which enables the user to add products to the Quote.  The problem is that if the ModelState is not valid on the POST (say the user has forgotten to enter a required phone number), the partial view(s) of the products are not returned to the view.  What must I do to have the QuoteDetails returned to the user?

Here is the main view:

```
@model CMSUsersAndRoles.Models.QuoteViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Quote</h4>
        <hr />
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.QuoteId)
            </div>
        </div>
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Company, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CustomerId, new SelectList(ViewBag.Customers, "CustomerId", "Company"), "---Select one---", new { style = "width: 300px !important", htmlAttributes = new { @class = "company" } });
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Company, new { @class = "companyName" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Company, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

            </div>
        </div>

... //other Quote fields

<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.QuoteDetail, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10" id="QuoteDetails">
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.QuoteDetail, "", new { @class = "text-danger"})

 @Ajax.ActionLink("Add product", "AddProduct", "QuoteViewModel", new { quoteId = Model.QuoteId, quoteDetailId = (Model.QuoteDetail.Count + 1) }, new AjaxOptions
           {
               UpdateTargetId = "QuoteDetails",
               InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertBefore
           })

            </div>
```

Here is the partial view:

```
@model CMSUsersAndRoles.Models.QuoteDetail

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "EditQuoteDetail";
    Layout = null;
}


    <div id="row" class="row">
        <table>

            @using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("quoteDetail"))

            {

                <tr>
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.QuoteId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.QuoteDetailId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SKU, new { htmlAttributes = new { @readonly = "readonly", @id = "SKU", @class = "form-control", style = "width: 100px" } })
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ProductId, new SelectList(ViewBag.ProductData, "ProductId", "Name"), "---Select one---", new { style = "width: 300px !important", required = "required", htmlAttributes = new { @id = "ProductName", @class = "ProductList" } })
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ProductName)

                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Amount, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "Amt", @class = "form-control amount", style = "width: 95px" } })
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ListPrice, new { htmlAttributes = new { @readonly = "readonly", @id = "LPrce", @class = "form-control listprice", style = "width: 95px" } })
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Discount, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "TotalDiscount", @class = "form-control discount", style = "width: 100px" } })
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Price, new { htmlAttributes = new { @readonly = "readonly", @id = "FinalPrce", @class = "form-control price", style = "width: 100px" } })


                    @Ajax.ActionLink(" ", "DeleteProduct", "QuoteViewModel", new { quoteId = Model.QuoteId, quoteDetailId = (Model.QuoteDetailId) },
                          new AjaxOptions
                          {
                              HttpMethod = "POST",
                              Confirm = "Are you Sure You Want to Delete " + Model.ProductName,
                              OnSuccess = "RemoveRow"
                          },
                          new { @class = "btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-trash" })
                </tr>
            }

        </table>
    </div>
```

Here is the POST:

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
       public ActionResult Create(QuoteViewModel qvm)
        {
            if (qvm.QuoteDetail == null)
            {
                qvm.QuoteDetail = new List<QuoteDetail>();
                qvm.QuoteDetail.Add(new QuoteDetail() { QuoteId = qvm.QuoteId, QuoteDetailId = (qvm.QuoteDetail.Count + 1) });
                var customerList = db.Customers.ToList();
                ViewBag.Customers = customerList;
                return View(qvm);
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

             ... //process

return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            var customers = db.Customers.ToList();
            ViewBag.Customers = customers;

            return View(qvm);
        }
```

Here is the code to load the partial view:

```
public ActionResult AddProduct(int quoteId, int quoteDetailId)
        {
            var items = db.Products.ToList();
            ViewBag.ProductData = items;

            return PartialView("EditQuoteDetail", new QuoteDetail { QuoteId = quoteId, QuoteDetailId = quoteDetailId });
        }
```

Here is the relevant section of the ViewModel:

```
public class QuoteViewModel
    {  // Columns from QuoteDetail table
        [Required(ErrorMessage ="Please add product(s) to quote   ")]
        [Display(Name = "Quote Detail")]
        public List<QuoteDetail> QuoteDetail { get; set; }
    }
```

What am I missing?  Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You need to show your model for `QuoteViewModel` - does it contain a property named `quoteDetail` which is a collection of `QuoteDetail`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke, added above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main view needs to include a loop to generate the html for any existing `QuoteDetail` (which will include those that you have added dynamically).

In your GET method, or in a default constructor for `QuoteViewModel`, ensure you initialize your `QuoteDetail` to a new collection so its not `null`. Then in the view, add the following code

```
@foreach(var detail in Model.QuoteDetail)
{
    @Html.Partial("EditQuoteDetail", detail)
}
```

As a side note, you should be using a view model for `QuoteDetail`, and it should not include property `QuoteId`

Comment: Thank you!  That fixed the issue.